# Immutable Memoization - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I'm trying to keep my front-end stack as functionally pure and immutable as possible and its done wonders for this project.

It is said all algorithms that can be implemented mutably can be implemented immutably, so in javascript how would I implement an immutable function memoizer? Because in order to return through a different path in the function some state inside or outside the function would have to change.

With the following function, how you can have an immutable memoization in javascript?

```
function once(fn){
  let returnValue;
  let canRun = true;
  return function runOnce(){
      if(canRun) {
          returnValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
          canRun = false;
      }
      return returnValue;
  }
}
var processonce = once(process);
processonce(); //process
processonce(); //
```

Comment: Memoization inherently relies on state, it cannot be removed. At best, you could make it "pure functional" by passing the state around explicitly. State would be immutable data structure, but a different one after each call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also curious about this question. I agree with @zch - passing the immutable state around would work (the initial call will initialize recursion with empty state).

So, I did my homework with implementing Fibonacci function: remember, we need it at least twice for `n-1` and for `n-2`. When we call `fib(n-2)` - it is already memoized.

Here is my implementation:

```
const resultCombination = cache => result => (getResult = true) => getResult ? result : cache
const cacheResult = ({resultCombination}) => result => n => resultCombination({...result(false), [n]: result()})(result())

const memoize = ({resultCombination, cacheResult}) => cache => f => n => cache.hasOwnProperty(n)
    ? resultCombination(cache)(cache[n])
    : cacheResult({resultCombination})(f(cache)(n))(n)

const fib2 = ({resultCombination, cacheResult, memoize}) => f1Result => f => n => resultCombination(f1Result(false))(f1Result() + memoize({resultCombination, cacheResult})(f1Result(false))(f)(n - 2)())

const fib = ({resultCombination, cacheResult, memoize, fib2}) => cache => n => n === 1 || n === 2
    ? resultCombination(cache)(1)
    : fib2({resultCombination, cacheResult, memoize})(memoize({resultCombination, cacheResult})(cache)(fib({resultCombination, cacheResult, memoize, fib2}))(n - 1))(fib({resultCombination, cacheResult, memoize, fib2}))(n)


console.log('THE RESULT: ' + fib({
    resultCombination,
    cacheResult: ({resultCombination}) => result => n => {
        console.log(`Caching result: f(${n})=${result()}`)
        return cacheResult({resultCombination})(result)(n)
    },
    memoize: ({resultCombination, cacheResult}) => cache => f => n => {
        console.log(cache.hasOwnProperty(n) ? `Cache hit for n=${n}` : `Calculating value for f(${n})`)
        return memoize({resultCombination, cacheResult})(cache)(f)(n)
    },
    fib2
})({})(8)(true))

// Calculating value for f(7)
// Calculating value for f(6)
// Calculating value for f(5)
// Calculating value for f(4)
// Calculating value for f(3)
// Calculating value for f(2)
// Caching result: f(2)=1
// Calculating value for f(1)
// Caching result: f(1)=1
// Caching result: f(3)=2
// Cache hit for n=2
// Caching result: f(4)=3
// Cache hit for n=3
// Caching result: f(5)=5
// Cache hit for n=4
// Caching result: f(6)=8
// Cache hit for n=5
// Caching result: f(7)=13
// Cache hit for n=6
// THE RESULT: 21
```

For better understanding, what's going on - the `cacheResult` and `memoize` functions are injected with logging wrappers. As you can see, all functions are pure, taking only one parameter (except dependency injection).

Be sure, that `resultCombination(cache)(result)` - is just replacement of `{cache, result}` data structure.

P.S. I'm not a Haskell nerd (even don't know the Haskell or Lisp syntax at all), but I'm passionate about functional programming

Comment: Very interesting, i'll take a look more thoroughly at this when i'm home after work. Looks solid, however i'm trying to avoid passing around something that signifies "cache" or "not cache" and have the function inherently know whether its been called or not called before.

Obviously this requires mutability to some degree but if that mutability  could exist somewhere outside of my codebase (For example in the javascript engine itself) then that is something i'd be fine with.

Comment: Than I suggest to use some libraries or frameworks, that have this implementation. For example, Redux does state mutation, but according to Redux ideology, all the mutations are immutable, and you should have one single global storage. For example, I have my library implementing memoization aligned with Redux interface (but not obligatory Redux - you can write adapter to be compliant with Redux interface and my library). https://github.com/blackakula/redux-composite/blob/master/README.md#memoize - the library allows me to be flexible and modular and still having single global state.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different io aproach, using generators can we say it's pure ?

```js
function* _cache() {
    const value = yield null
    while (true) yield value
}

const cache = _cache()

const heavyComputation = i => {
        console.log(`uh oh that's some heavy computations here`)
        return i++
}

cache.next().value
cache.next(heavyComputation(1))
cache.next().value
cache.next().value
```

you can then use it to cache a value at runtime

```js
function* _cache() {
    const value = yield null
    while (true) yield value
}

const cache = _cache()
const loadMongo = uri => void console.log(`fully loaded ${uri}`)

function end(loadedMongo) {
    console.log('handler called')
}

function handler() {
    const mongoUri = 'salutos speculos'
    const loaded = cache.next().value
    if (loaded === null) {
        cache.next(loadMongo(mongoUri))
        end(cache.next().value)
    } else end(loaded)
}

handler()
handler()
handler()
handler()
handler()
```

[image]